# How does Gram–Schmidt process produce normalized, orthogonal rows?

Tags: linear-algebra, gram-schmidt

Assuming a square matrix, I see how this process would produce orthonormal columns, but I cannot see the rows also turn out to be orthonormal after this process? It seems like some kind of witchery.

edit: to clarify, I don't see how a square matrix whose columns are normalized and pairwise orthogonal, implies that it's rows will also be normalized and pairwise orthogonal

Comment: It's immaterial which technique you use to construct a set of orthonormal columns—whether it's the Gram-Schmidt or any other procefure. If the columns of $\ U\ $ are orthonormal then
$$
U^\top U=I
$$
—that is $\ U^\top=U^{-1}\ $, and therefore
$$
UU^\top=UU^{-1}=I\  
$$
so the rows of $\ U\ $ are also orthonormal.

Comment: This is sometimes shown in matrix form conveniently. A matrix $A$ has orthonormal columns iff $A^TA = I$. But then $A^{-1} = A^T$, and thus $A A^T = I$ as well. This is equivalent to the rows being orthonormal.

Comment: Maybe the question should be, why the matrix equation is true geometrically. It is incredibly useful, but I find it counterintuitive too.

Comment: maybe I am not expressing the question well, I don't understand how creating a square matrix, whose columns are normalized and pairwise orthogonal, implies that the rows will also be normalized and pairwise orthogonal.

Comment: "...that is $U^T=U^{-1}$'' cheats because it is invertible precisely when the other relation holds as well, $UU^T=I$.

Comment: The point (as [DisintegratingByParts's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3734986) makes clear) is that the orthonormality of the columns of $\ U\ $ implies that $\ U^\top\ $ is a *left* inverse of $\ U\ $, and left inverses of matrices are also *right* inverses. That $\ U^\top\ $ is a right inverse of $\ U\ $ then implies that the *rows* of $\ U\ $ are orthonormal.  Thus, though I can see why the implication might appear surprising, it is really no more mysterious than the fact that left inverses of matrices are also right inverses.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera True but the argument that $U^TU=I\implies $ ("that is") $U^T=U^{-1}$ "and therefore" $UU^T=I$, is not correct.

Comment: @Chrystomath I'm afraid I don't follow. Which step of the argument is not correct?  If $\ U^\top U=I\ $, then $\ U^\top\ $ is, by definition, a left inverse of $\ U\ $, which (for matrices) automatically makes it a right inverse as well, and conventionally denotable by $\ U^{-1}\ $.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera You're supplying the missing steps yourselves. It is not automatic that left inverses are right inverses. You did not mention that in your comment, and it is false in general. For example, the left and right shift operators satisfy $R^TR=I$ but it does not follow that $RR^T=I$.

Answer (score 0):

No, after getting then you have to normalize them. Suppose $\vec a, \vec b, \vec c$ are linearly independent non-orthogonal vectors then we can create $\vec u, \vec v, \vec w$ by G-S procedure as
$$\vec u= \vec a, ~~\vec v= \vec b+ r \vec u, ~~s.t~~ \vec v. \vec u=0 \implies r=-\frac{\vec a. \vec b}{\vec a. \vec a}$$
Bext lert $\vec w=\vec c+s \vec u+t \vec v ~~s.t~~ \vec w.\vec u=0=\vec w. \vec v.$
We can determine scalars $s$ and $t$, After most (not in between) we can normalize
$\vec u, \vec v, \vec w$ to get orthonormal basis as $(\hat u, \hat v, \hat w)$

Comment: The G-S procedure, as it is described on wikipedia, *includes* normalizing the columns along with making them pairwise orthogonal.

Comment: It is a policy matter, normalizing in between is cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

The Gram-Schmidt process applies to any matrix, even rectangular ones. Even if one neglects cases where the GS vectors are linearly dependent, the rows of a GS matrix in general are *not* orthogonal. Only when there are $n$ linearly independent vectors does it turn out to be unitary.

For example, orthogonalization of this matrix of columns gives $$\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\2&0\\2&1\end{pmatrix}\mapsto \frac{1}{3}\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\2&-2\\2&1\end{pmatrix}=:A$$ The rows are not orthogonal. Compare with a full matrix: $$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1\\2&0&2\\2&1&3\end{pmatrix}\mapsto \frac{1}{3}\begin{pmatrix}1&2&-2\\2&-2&-1\\2&1&2\end{pmatrix}=:U$$

Notice how, by definition of GS, $A^TA=I_{2\times2}$. So, what does $A$ do? It maps $\mathbb{R}^2$ into a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$. And $A^T$? It maps back from $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that the plane becomes $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the plane's normal becomes $0$. (This is because $A^Tn=\begin{pmatrix}a_1\cdot n\\a_2\cdot n\\\vdots\end{pmatrix}=0$.)

In a square non-degenerate matrix, there is no normal left over, so $U^T$ has no null vectors. Again, by construction $U^TU=I$, and $Ue_i=u_i$ are the column vectors, while $U^Tu_i=U^TUe_i=e_i$. Since the $u_i$ span the whole vector space, any vector $v$ can be written as a linear combination of them, so $$UU^Tv=UU^T(\sum_i\alpha_iu_i)=U(\sum_i\alpha_ie_i)=\sum_i\alpha_iu_i=v$$ Hence $UU^T=I$, which states that the rows are orthonormal.

Comment: I was assuming a square matrix, but did not specify (edited the question to clarify), I am confounded as two how making the columns pairwise orthogonal and normalized, implies the rows will be as well

Answer (score 0):

The witchery comes from working in finite-dimensional spaces, where the left inverse of a square matrix is always the same as the right inverse.

**Theorem**: If $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over a field $\mathscr{F}$, and if $A$ is an invertible linear transformation on $V$, then $A^{-1}$ is a polynomial in $A$ and, hence, commutes with $A$. So every left inverse of $A$ is a right inverse and vice-versa.

**Proof:** Suppose $V$ is an invertible $n\times n$ matrix, and suppose
$$
       m(\lambda) = \lambda^n+a_{n-1}\lambda^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1\lambda+a_0
$$
is its minimal polynomial. Then $a_0\ne 0$ because that would imply
$$
                (A^{n-1}+a_{n-1}A^{n-2}+\cdots+a_1I)A=0,
$$
and the invertibility of $A$ would imply that $A^{n-1}+a_{n-1}A^{n-2}+\cdots+a_1I=0$, which would contradict the minimality of the polynomial $m$.
Therefore,
$$
             A^{-1}=\frac{1}{a_0}(A^{n-1}+a_{n-1}A^{n-2}+\cdots+a_1I).
$$
Hence, a left inverse of $A$ will always be a right inverse because it must commute with $A$. $\;\;\blacksquare$

The inverse of a square orthogonal matrix $U$ is its transpose $U^{\perp}$. Therefore,
$$
                U^{\perp}U=I \iff UU^{\perp}=I
$$
The first equality is equivalent to the columns of $U$ forming an orthonormal basis. The second equality is equivalent to the rows of $U$ forming an orthonormal basis.